# Taking data from database and passing it to the view with a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to show some data in some in some bootstrap textboxes.

Normally in Webforms I'd set a dataset and set the .Text properties of textboxes by using something like `TextBox.Text=Datatable.Rows[0]["FieldName"].ToString()` but being new to MVC got me clueless.

Anyways here is what I have

I have an actionresult like this, where I get the data from DB. Data comes nicely. All I need to do is get them hooked together.

```
public ActionResult CompanySettings()
        {
            ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            int CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(identity.FindFirst("CompanyId").Value);
            //-----------------------------
            ViewBag.CompanyId = CompanyId;
            ViewBag.Page = "Inbox";
            string Name = identity.Name;
            string CompanyName = identity.FindFirst("CompanyName").Value;



            ViewBag.Name = Name;
            ViewBag.CompanyName = CompanyName;
            //-----------------------------

            DataSet ds = CompanyDB.Company_Get_Info(CompanyId);
            return View();
        }
```

and my ViewModel (showing only one field as a n example)

```
public class CompanySettingViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "CompanyType")]
        public CompanyType CompanyType { get; set; }

        //and many more fields like this.
    }
```

I'm posting my html part too in any case

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="registerbox-textbox">
          <h6>Company Type</h6>
       @Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(t=>t.CompanyType).Placeholder("FirmaTipi")
      </div>
    </td>
//again many repeating same type fields inside a table
<tr>
<table>
```

This is probably something very simple and easy but I'm stuck. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public ActionResult CompanySettings()
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        int CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(identity.FindFirst("CompanyId").Value);
        //-----------------------------
        ViewBag.CompanyId = CompanyId;
        ViewBag.Page = "Inbox";
        string Name = identity.Name;
        string CompanyName = identity.FindFirst("CompanyName").Value;



        ViewBag.Name = Name;
        ViewBag.CompanyName = CompanyName;
        //-----------------------------

        DataSet ds = CompanyDB.Company_Get_Info(CompanyId);
        CompanySettingViewModel NewModel= new CompanySettingViewModel();
        NewModel.CompanyType = "AnyValue" //Pass the Company Type value to model 
        return View(NewModel);
    }
```

and your view will be

```
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="registerbox-textbox">
          <h6>Company Type</h6>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(t=>t.CompanyType,  new { @placeholder = "FirmaTipi" })
      </div>
    </td>
//again many repeating same type fields inside a table
<tr>
<table>
```